# getPreviewFormat and setPreviewFormat on Android api level 7

Tags: android-camera, android

The methods of Camera.Parameters setPreviewFormat() and getPreviewFormat() accept and return an int respectively. The int should correspond to one of those specified by ImageFormat class, but this class was introduced only with api level 8, while the two methods above are there since api level 1. How to know the image format (rgb888? yuv? other?) of the camera preview when using api level 7?

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the existing ImageFormats on Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html

But as you said, this class is available since API Level 8....
Probably those parametres were inside of the Camera class before the API 7.

Comment: I know the ImageFormat class, but i am unable to understand what was the usage of those methods before api level 8, if one didn't know the meaning of the int returned by getPreviewFormat() and what to pass to setPreviewFormat()...

Answer (score 0):

Before API level 8 they had this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html